# How use multiple times the same association in HQL?

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, hql

I use Java with Spring Boot, and especially Spring Data JPA.

In an existing database,
there are 2 tables A and B
with B having a foreign key pointing to A.

In my code,
i have the 2 entities

```
@Table(schema = "TEST", name = "A")
public class Deliver implements Serializable {

    @OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "deliver")
    private List<B> parameters;
}

@Table(schema = "TEST", name = "B")
public class Parameters implements Serializable {

    @ManyToOne
    ....
}
```

I want to translate to HQL query this following SQL request:

```
select a.ID
from A a
join B b as b1 on a.ID = b1.A_ID
join B b as b2 on a.ID = b2.A_ID
join B b as b3 on a.ID = b3.A_ID
where b1.type = 'Client' and b1.value = 'INDIA'
and   b2.type = 'Site' and b2.value = 'BENGALURU'
and   b3.type = 'Laboratory' and b3.value = 'CHEMISTRY';
```

The problem is that I have only @OneToMany relation between entity A and entity B, and in my case, I want to use 3 times this relation i.e join 3 times the entity Parameters (table B) from entity Deliver (table A).

Have you make it in an elegant way in HQL?

Comment: I will try : select deliver from Deliver join deliver.parameters  parameters1  join deliver.parameters parameters2  join deliver.parameters parameters3 where parameters1.type = and parameters1.value = and parameters2.type = and parameters2.value = and parameters3.type = and parameters3.value =

Comment: The precedent code (those of my precedent comment) does not work now